# vcpu counts aren't changing after config change and reboot

Tags: virsh, vcpu

I recently downsized the number of vcpus virtual server Echobox1 uses from 4 to 1.

before:

```
# virsh vcpucount Echobox1
maximum      config         4
maximum      live           4
current      config         4
current      live           4
```

I restarted this server using

```
virsh reboot Echobox1
```

However the live vcpucount still shows 4:

```
# virsh vcpucount Echobox1
maximum      config         1
maximum      live           4
current      config         1
current      live           4
```

What else is needed to reset the live vcpucount? I could restart the entire virtual server, but I'd prefer not having to do that since I have multiple other systems running under it.

**Note**: I am unable to use the --live option on this machine.

```
# virsh setvcpus Echobox1 1 --live
error: unsupported configuration: failed to find appropriate hotpluggable vcpus to reach the desired target vcpu count
```

TL;DR:

How do I reset the **live** vcpucount after changing the config file?

Answer (score 1):

This was actually easier than expected.  To reset the live vcpu count, shut down the virtual server, then start it.  Simply rebooting it won't update that live count.

```
# virsh shutdown Echobox1
# virsh start Echobox1
```